# Cassandra: How to SKIP Rows in paging?

Tags: cassandra, paging, nosql

Can we use the paging in Cassandra without using paging state? I mean, what should we do if we want to have random access (jump in) to page 3 after first page, for example?

Answer (score 6):

There is a trick.

Imagine you have a table

```
CREATE TABLE (
   partition uuid,
   clustering uuid,
   column1 text,
   ...
   columnN text,
   PRIMARY KEY((partition), clustering)
)
```

For the first page with 10 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10;
```

On the client-side, save the partition value for the **last** row e.g. **10th** row. For the second page (11th to 20th row):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE token(partition) > token('value_of_10th_partition') LIMIT 10;
```

For the third page (21st to 30th row):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE token(partition) > token('value_of_20th_partition') LIMIT 10;
```

It means that

1. **for the first time**, if you want to reach **page N**, you'll need to fetch all previous **N-1** pages
2. you need to save the **last** partition value for each page to be
   able to access the next page. For example, if you want to access
   page n°34, you'll need to save the **last** partition value for page
   n°33
3. this technique does **not** guarantee isolation e.g. in the
   meantime, if there are new data being inserted into Cassandra, it
   may add extra entries in the page so that the page n°30 for example
   may not contain the same rows after the insert of new data. Using
   PagingState object does not solve this issue either. This is because
   we do not create a snapshot of each page (and we don't want to do
   this, too expensive) so there is **no isolation**.

Comment: Since, we are using c# driver in app site, manipulate token is unavailable, then.

Comment: `token()` is a CQL system function so it is available for all Cassandra drivers, C# included

Comment: The token function can only be used the way you described when ByteOrderedPartitioner (deprecated) is selected for the cluster.

Comment: @endriu Wrong. Token(partition_key) will apply the Partitioner hash function to the partition key value to obtain a hash value (called token). Technically, whatever Partitioner you choose (Murmur3, Random or ByteOrderer) the hash values are always ordered